# Open file in Python

Tags: python, django

My cwd is ~/Desktop/Development/Python/djcode/mysite, and I want to open a file on my Desktop. What is the syntax to open files in a different directory? (for example, if the file was in the cwd I would use open('file'). Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried?  Please post the code you're using and the error message your getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use relative paths? `../../../../file`

Comment: Right, thank you. I was trying ~ to get to the home directory, but I guess it doesn't recognize that in the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
>>> import os
>>> path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/foo.txt')
>>> open(path, 'r')
<open file '/home/pat/Desktop/foo.txt', mode 'r' at 0x7f0455af0db0>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the path to it, either absolute:

```
myfile = open('/path/to/myfile.ext')
```

or relative:

```
myfile = open('../../../../myfile.ext')
```

depending on which is more appropriate for the situation. You can use [os.path.expanduser()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to expand the `~` portion of the path.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use absolute path to the file, because if you move your program to another location or another computer, relative paths will break.
2. Use context manager while opening the file.

> ```
> with open('c:\absolutepath\file') as f:
>    content = f.read()
> ```